# What is the probability that the classifier will make at most 1 correct classification?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

An email spam filter correctly classifies mails (i.e. a spam mail as spam, a not-spam as not-spam) 2/3 of the
times. Classification decisions are independent of each other. You test the classifier with a set of 3 emails.
The classifier will stop when it performs one wrong classification (e.g. when it says that a spam email is not
spam, or vice-versa), or when it correctly classifies all 3 emails.

** I have first done the binomial way. since they are asking for at most one so its 0 and 1.

$
\binom{3}{0}= \frac{3!}{0!(3!)} \cdot \frac{2}{3^0} \cdot \frac{1}{3^3} = 0.03703
$

$
\binom{3}{1}= \frac{3!}{1!(2!)} \cdot \frac{2}{3^1} \cdot \frac{1}{3^2} = 0.22222
$

when i add both of them i get 0.25925.

is this correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain more of what you mean by the "binomial way", i.e. what the different terms in your equations are? Just asking, because: $\binom{3}{0} = 1$ and $\binom{3}{1} = 3$.